# What year mustang is this and does anyone know the size of the hood

Tags: ford, mustang, old-cars

I just bought this car and am trying to buy new parts to fix it up does anyone know what kind of car mustang it is and what the size of hood is [image]

Comment: Ford have a webpage that will give you the build info from the vin - check it out.

Comment: Looks like a mid-80s version to me, but hard to say for sure. I agree with @SolarMike in that you should ask Ford.

Comment: Agree with Mike and GdD. Regarding the hood, have you thought about using a tape measure and uh, measuring it?

Comment: If you look inside the driver's door frame, it will probably have a sticker with the vin, tire pressure, etc., and may have the year, and other vehicle information.

Comment: Online manufacturer VIN decoders typically don't go back to the early 1980s.   For 1981 and after, the tenth digit will give you the model year. B=1981, C=1982, D=1983, E=1984, F=1985, G=1986, and so on.    The certification label (on driver's door frame) will definitely include the build date (e.g., 10/85 for a MY1986 car).

Answer (score 1):

It's a 3rd Generation Mustang (or "Fox" / "Foxybody"), produced from 1979 to 1993.  Specifically, it's a "Four Eyes" car produced between 1979 and 1986, the '87 onwards car had a re-styled front end.

There is plenty information on the [Mustang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford_Mustang#Third_generation_(1979%E2%80%931993)) Wikipedia page about this model.  [FourEyedPride](http://foureyedpride.com/) has some more detailed owners info around this model.

Sorry, I can't give you hood dimensions but you ought to be able to measure the one you have.  Good luck with the restoration!

Comment: 1979-1986 it is.  If you have access to the car, you can read the VIN from the windshield.  For 1981 and after, the tenth digit will give you the model year.   B=1981, C=1982, D=1983, E=1984, F=1985, G=1986, and so on.